# iPad ajax problems

Tags: javascript, ajax, ipad, safari

Long story short: I had to create a chat functionality which seems to work on all devices except the iPad (and possibly the iPhone). Our customer uses their iPads to chat and so I have tried to solve the problems for past 7-ish months.

That's how long it took for me to somewhat pinpoint the problem.

The problem is clearly in the iPad's browser. I run JSON Ajax requests using the library jQuery. The requests are fine, they do not contain errors. At some point, the iPad just doesn't run Ajax requests at all. I dont know why, I cant find why. Every Ajax request is logged, but at some point the server doesn't get any requests. I have asked a zillion times and the customer is positive they are only touching the ipad to prevent it from being locked.

I have reduced the rate of requests to approximately 15 requests per minute, but that didn't work.

So, my question is: **Is there any information known to man why the ipad abruptly stops sending Ajax requests after 10-15 minutes?**

Comment: Does it work on Safari on a computer?

Comment: are you making asynchronous requests? are you setting cached = false?

Comment: Have you made a minimal test app that we can look at? Perhaps set up a PHP file that AJAX's itself, then returns the time every 10 seconds or something. Does it have the same problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting this here, as in comment there isn't any syntax highlighting.

I've made a super minimal test page here: http://www.focalstrategy.com/tests/ajax.php

The code is:

```
<?

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

echo date("F j, Y, G:i:s a");
exit();

}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Ajax Test</h1>
    <p>This page makes an AJAX request every 5 seconds and replaces the div below with the returned date.</p>

    <div><p id="date"><?= date("F j, Y, G:i:s a") ?></p></div>
    <div><p><span id="count">0</span> updates made.</p></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var count = 0;

    var getDate = function() {
        $.get('/tests/ajax.php', function(data) {
            $('#date').html(data);
            count = count + 1;
            $('#count').html(count);
        });
    }
    setInterval(getDate, 5000);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

So, I ran this for an hour, and didn't have any issues, the iPad (fully updated) ran fine throughout, without missing any.

I also ran this on Chrome and recorded it's behaviour. This looks like this:

[image: Chrome Profiler view, showing graphs for DOM Node, Event Listeners and memory usage.]

([Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLbIo.png))

There's some weirdness here, in that at first the number of event listeners stays constant, then after a while goes mad,, increasing up to 56 listeners before dropping to 1 again. The DOM Node Count also repeatedly spikes, as high as 424. Both have fairly odd behaviour bearing in mind the simplicity of this code.

Perhaps on your app the number of Dom Nodes being tracked, or the number of event listeners is reaching some value causing the iPad to lose track of what's happening, or something similar.

It's also worth noticing that the memory usage ramps up until garbage collection happens. That's what is meant to happen, though perhaps it's less efficient on the iPad.

Edit: I've tested it again on a clean profile, many of the Event listeners are due to extensions – the same behaviour happens, but not to same degree, also background values are 0-1 rather than 15-20

Comment: I'm running the diagnostics for a while as well, with some interaction (to see if interaction cause memory leaks or anything) though memory seems fine. The only peak is in the first 2.5 minutes (12mb) but after that it stays below 5mb so I highly doubt that's the problem. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: It's sort of weird really. I was hoping to see some catastrophic build up of something causing the iPad to give up... Perhaps their iPads are losing Wifi connection briefly, making the requests stop. I don't know if the iPad will continue asking after that. To get round this, you could run the code in an iframe, then every 10 minutes refresh the iFrame or something.

Comment: I've been looking to see if there is anything inherently wrong with this approach, but can't see much. Obviously looking at long polling,  or comet or something is probably not worth the hassle here, but it's something to think about.

Comment: I've asked a few people if that behaviour in the graph is “right” or not, but they are in a different timezone. I'll post any reply if/once I've got them!

Comment: Thanks for all the effort man! Yeah the problem is quite frustrating. A third company has gone through all the source code and has ran diagnostics but they simply could not find the problem either. Instead, they started to wonder if the chats they have built work on ipads too, quite amusing really but still didn't fix my problem :(

Comment: I'd suggest moving to websockets - something like http://code.google.com/p/jquery-graceful-websocket/ can make it easier, but the server side bit is hard if your server doesn't support it. This avoids polling repeatedly, and is how the notifications on your inbox on SO work.

Comment: The target audience for the website are mothers and grandmothers. I don't expect granny surfing the web with an websocket-enabled browser hehe. I've updated the website again today, so far so good! If there are no further problems in the future I'll just vote your answer as correct answer since you really helped a lot! :)

Comment: The iPad has websockets though…

Comment: Glad to be of help, I learnt a bit as well, so all is good :)

Comment: I know the iPad does, but there are two chatters: an employee on the back-end and a client on the front-end. The client on the front end could use anything from the most recent Google Chrome to a potato. I guess I'm lucky if that potato supports AJAX, not to mention WebSockets!

Comment: OK. I assumed that you both connected to a server, in which case you could design it so that the protocol both use doesn't have to be the same.

Comment: We called an Apple expert and he confirmed that Safari on the iPad is very... annoying. Apple added a lot of security features to the Safari on the iPad (as I experienced before) and there are no workarounds. We either have to make an app or use another device since it works flawless on desktops and even on my Android phone. I've also found Opera for iPad, though I'm not sure if that helps. Thank you SO much for all your help. Instead of hugging I will just give the bounty to you! Well deserved!