# Different behavior on browser from IPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf, ipad

I have built an application in *HTML5* and I use *JQuery Ajax* for manipulating the data to sql server database.

For this application I use *wcf* service for getting and posting that data through stored procedures.

On browser(chrome) everything works fine, even if the server is overloaded (the ajax will wait for response from the server).

I wrapped this app on IPad with xCode, and I noticed that the Ajax works with different behavior. If the server is overloaded, and for example some procedure executes for instance 1 minute, ajax will not wait for the true response of that procedure/method from the wcf service, it goes in error immediately.

I try to use `.done()` instead of `.success()`, and it doesn't help me, I also try to set `timeout:60000//60sec` on the ajax and still nothing, so I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801833/ipad-ajax-problems  `We called an Apple expert and he confirmed that Safari on the iPad is very... annoying. Apple added a lot of security features to the Safari on the iPad (as I experienced before) and there are no workarounds. We either have to make an app or use another device since it works flawless on desktops and even on my Android phone. I've also found Opera for iPad, though I'm not sure if that helps.`